# .htaccess redirecting broken URLs

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I updated a website but the links doesn't work properly anymore. I have some urls but they don't work anymore:

```
http://www.mysite.eu/fr/some-page
http://www.mysite.eu/fr/some-page1
http://www.mysite.eu/fr/some-page2
```

Is it possible to redirect the page when there is an `/fr/` in the url? 
I've tried

```
Redirect 301 /fr/ http://www.mysite.eu/
```

but that only strips the `/fr/`.

Comment: Because Your redirect will use 301 redirection when it matches `http://www.mysite.eu/fr/` and redirect to `http://www.mysite.eu/`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Redirect to the same URL but without the `fr/` part? Do you also have `mod_rewrite` activated?

Comment: @Havelock The site doesn't support FR anymore so the links with /fr/ need to be directed to the root/homepage.

Comment: How about `mod_rewrite`? If you've tagged your question with `wordpress` then I would suppose you have it activated.

Comment: @Havelock Yes this is what I have:

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: Why not changing your `RewriteBase` from `/` to `fr/` ?

Comment: @OfirBaruch because the pages under `fr/` have status `301` or in other words - no longer there...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great! So if you have `mod_rewrite` activated you can rewrite the broken links, instead of redirecting them

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^fr/(.)*$ / [R=301,NC,L]  # Added line
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule> 
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Pure awesomeness! Works Perfect. Thanks a lot Havelock!